# Laravel 7 Cookie documentation no more forever and forgot

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Anyone know how to make and forget cookie in Laravel 7.

The documentation under
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie only have 2 methods.

and under namespace Illuminate\Cookie; The classname CookieJar do have the function.

But I can't get the below code work:-

```
Cookie::forget('staff_name');
Cookie::forget('staff_id');

Cookie::forever('staff_name', $request->get('name'));
Cookie::forever('staff_id', $request->get('id'));
```

but I manage to make it work by using `queue` method.

```
    Cookie::queue('staff_name', $request->get('name'),-200000);
    Cookie::queue('staff_id', $request->get('id'), -200000);

    Cookie::queue('staff_name', $request->get('name'), 100000);
    Cookie::queue('staff_id', $request->get('id'), 100000);
```

Any idea what is the correct way use cookie in Laravel 7?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#cookies ?

Comment: I do read the documentation, I am ask for the `forget` and `forever` no more support or what is the proper way to do it in version 7?